# Difference between std::remove and erase for vector?

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I have a doubt that I would like to clarify in my head. I am aware of the different behavior  for `std::vector` between `erase` and `std::remove` where the first physically removes an element from the vector, reducing size, and the other just moves an element leaving the capacity the same.

Is this just for efficiency reasons? By using `erase`, all elements in a `std::vector` will be shifted by 1, causing a large amount of copies; `std::remove` does just a 'logical' delete and leaves the vector unchanged by moving things around. If the objects are heavy, that difference might matter, right?

Comment: @larsmans, you're wrong. OP is correct - there is `std::remove` template function which does what OP says.

Comment: @larsmans Incorrect.  `std::remove` is an algorithm for marking elements in a collection as removed.

Comment: See "Item 32" of Scott Meyers, "Effective STL", Addison-Wesley, 2001, pp. 139-143.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

> Is this just for efficiency reason? By using erase all elements in a std::vector will be shifted by 1 causing a large amount of copies; std::remove does just a 'logical' delete and leaves the vector unchanged by moving things around. If the objects are heavy that difference mihgt matter, right?

The reason for using this idiom is exactly that. There is a benefit in performance, but not in the case of a single erasure. Where it does matter is if you need to remove multiple elements from the vector. In this case, the `std::remove` will copy each *not removed* element only once to its final location, while the `vector::erase` approach would move all of the elements from the position to the end multiple times. Consider:

```
std::vector<int> v{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
// remove all elements < 5
```

If you went over the vector removing elements one by one, you would remove the 1, causing copies of the remainder elements that get shifted (4). Then you would remove 2 and shift all remainding elements by one (3)... if you see the pattern this is a `O(N^2)` algorithm.

In the case of `std::remove` the algorithm maintains a read and write heads, and iterates over the container. For the first 4 elements the read head will be moved and the element tested, but no element is copied. Only for the fifth element the object would be copied from the last to the first position, and the algorithm will complete with a single copy and returning an iterator to the second position. This is a `O(N)` algorithm. The later `std::vector::erase` with the range will cause destruction of all the remainder elements and resizing the container.

As others have mentioned, in the standard library algorithms are applied to iterators, and lack knowledge of the sequence being iterated. This design is more flexible than other approaches on which algorithms are aware of the containers in that a single implementation of the algorithm can be used with any sequence that complies with the iterator requirements. Consider for example, `std::remove_copy_if`, it can be used even without containers, by using iterators that generate/accept sequences:

```
std::remove_copy_if(std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin),
                    std::istream_iterator<int>(),
                    std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "),
                    [](int x) { return !(x%2); } // is even
                    );
```

That single line of code will filter out all even numbers from standard input and dump that to standard output, without requiring the loading of all numbers into memory in a container. This is the advantage of the split, the disadvantage is that the algorithms cannot modify the container itself, only the values referred to by the iterators.

Comment: THat's a great explanation! I was focused in removing just 1 element while I totally forgot that std::remove get rids of multiple elements. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @AbruzzoForteeGentile: In the case of removing a single element, both approaches are exactly the same with respect to cost. All of the elements from the location of the removed element to the end need to be copied/moved over and only the last element needs to be destroyed.

Answer (score 8):

`std::remove` is an algorithm from the STL which is quite container agnostic. It requires some concept, true, but it has been designed to also work with C arrays, which are static in sizes.

Answer (score 6):

`std::remove` simply returns a new `end()` iterator to point to one past the last non-removed element (the number of items from the returned value to `end()` will match the number of items to be removed, but there is no guarantee their values are the same as those you were removing - they are in a valid but unspecified state).  This is done so that it can work for multiple container types (basically any container type that a `ForwardIterator` can iterate through).

`std::vector::erase` actually sets the new `end()` iterator after adjusting the size.  This is because the `vector`'s method actually knows how to handle adjusting it's iterators (the same can be done with `std::list::erase`, `std::deque::erase`, etc.).

`remove` organizes a given container to remove unwanted objects.  The container's erase function actually handles the "removing" the way that container needs it to be done.  That is why they are separate.

Comment: *"after moving all of the removed items to the end of the container"* -- `std::remove` doesn't do that.  The elements at the end, starting from the returned position, are left in an unspecified state.

Comment: Since `remove` is basically swapping the elements to be removed with elements that are not going to be removed, the returned position to `end()` are all elements that will be removed (and are still in a valid state), but you are correct - there is no guarantee that they "match" the elements that were swapped out.  I'll clarify that a bit.

Comment: @ZacHowland:  The biggest difference now is that in C++11, `std::remove` is allowed to use move assignment, which will result in the range [result, end()) being nothing but moved-from elements.  The state of those elements is up to the class in question.

Comment: @ZacHowland, the most natural implementation of remove does not swap anything, it overwrites. remove essentially shifts all the unremoved items to the head of the vector, overwriting the removed ones.

Comment: @AdamBurry I was using the word "swap" interchangeably with "replace", but yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 5):

I think it has to do with needing direct access to the vector itself to be able to resize it.  std::remove only has access to the iterators, so it has no way of telling the vector "Hey, you now have fewer elements".

See yves Baumes answer as to why std::remove is designed this way.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, that's the gist of it. Note that `erase` is also supported by the other standard containers where its performance characteristics are different (e.g. [list::erase](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/erase/) is O(1)), while `std::remove` is container-agnostic and works with any type of [forward iterator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/ForwardIterator/) (so it works for e.g. bare arrays as well).

Answer (score 0):

Kind of.  Algorithms such as remove work on iterators (which are an abstraction to represent an element in a collection) which do not necessarily know which type of collection they are operating on - and therefore cannot call members on the collection to do the actual removal.

This is good because it allows algorithms to work generically on any container and also on ranges that are subsets of the entire collection.

Also, as you say, for performance - it may not be necessary to actually remove (and destroy) the elements if all you need is access to the logical end position to pass on to another algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Standard library algorithms operate on **sequences**. A sequence is defined by a pair of iterators; the first points at the first element in the sequence, and the second points one-past-the-end of the sequence. That's all; algorithms don't care where the sequence comes from.

Standard library containers hold data values, and provide a pair of iterators that specify a sequence for use by algorithms. They also provide member functions that may be able to do the same operations as an algorithm more efficiently by taking advantage of the internal data structure of the container.